# On what basis are tie-breakers decided in asphalt 8?

Tags: asphalt-8

I was racing in the Master Season. These are the results of the last race:
[image: results]

(My Username: Kesarling)

Can anyone explain why was I put 2nd? Is it because of Rank, or some other criterion?

Comment: I wonder if there are ten-thousandths of a second that are not shown.

Comment: In games, time is measured counting milliseconds elapsed between updates (usually each frame), so I don't think that 1/10000 seconds could be the tie-breaker. My guess is for the Rank.